# Parse error: Unexpected T_STRING on line 7

Tags: php

I know that these forums are flooded with dumb questions like these but this truly has me stumped! Any ideas?

```
define ("DB_NAME”, ”downloa6”); // set database name

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 7
```

Comment: `"` and `”` are not the same symbol. Find [an IDE that does syntax highlighting](http://www.sitepoint.com/best-php-ide-2014-survey-results/) to avoid this in the future.

Comment: Expanding  @DCoder's answer: single quote ```'``` and double quote ```"``` will tell to PHP: "the enclosed data is a string". Whatever other character you pass will have PHP trying to evaluate it.

Comment: Curly quotes; Beautiful, yet *deadly*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you copied and pasted this line from somewhere, replace the `”` with `"` and it should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different double quotes in your code, only one of which php recognizes.

```
define ("DB_NAME”, ”downloa6”); // set database name
        ^
```

This quote is the correct character, the others are not and PHP is interpreting them as part of the string rather than the end of the string. Use `"` instead.

Using a good IDE with syntax highlighting will help avoid this problem in future.